# select2 how ignore some selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-select2

I have initializing select2 like:

```
$('select').select2();
```

but now I have some `select` boxes, that not need `select2`, how I can add selector to `select2`, that will skipped and, `select2` will not initialize `select2` for that select box ?

How I cant skip:

```
<select class='skip-me'></select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`:not` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('select:not(.skip-me)').select2();
```

> **Description:** *Selects all elements that do not match the given selector.*

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do a loop searching for the selects and skiping the desired class selects. Something like this:

```
applySelectFormat();

function applySelectFormat(){ 
    $('select').each(function(){
        var e = $(this);
        if(!e.hasClass('skip-me')) e.select2();
    }
}
```

I think it's a solutions but it's not the best. You may have to test it if it takes more time to load the page...